# Pegar IP através do WinSock - Retornar IP correto - Delphi

Tags: delphi, redes, ip, vpn

Bom dia,

Estou usando o método abaixo para retornar o IP do computador, porém se eu tenho uma VPN ativa no computador, ele esta pegando primeiro o IP da VPN e não o da máquina. 
Gostaria de saber se seria possível controlar qual IP ele me retornar ou uma outra forma para eu poder pegar o IP real do computador (de uma placa de rede) e não da VPN e também se seria possível pegar apenas IPV4 e não IPV6.

Obrigado e aguardo.

Segue código:

```
function GetLocalIP: String;
var
ipwsa:TWSAData;
p:PHostEnt;
s:array[0..128] of char;
c : PAnsiChar;
begin
c := '';
try
  wsastartup(257,ipwsa);
  GetHostName(@s, 128);
  p := GetHostByName(@s);
  c := iNet_ntoa(PInAddr(p^.h_addr_list^)^);
except
  on E: Exception do
  begin
     TVSMLogUtils.GetInstance.LogE(E.Message);
  end;
end;
Result := String(c);
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve usar o GetAdaptersInfo(), depois filtre o resultado e escolha a LAN que deseja.

Neste [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/borland.public.delphi.language.delphi.win32/ooUJ1Bsn9sw) você vai encontrar o exemplo do código funcionando.

Comment: Obrigado deu certo.